# Alternative to vlookup approx match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, vlookup, vba

```
Row 1, Sheet 1: 
['0553400710', '0553439406']
```

Then i have an array like this in sheet 2,

```
Column 1     Column 2
Ahmed        0553400710
Someone      0542929292
Tina         0524449494
and so on
```

I used vlookup approx match but it gives wrong results by giving many matches.

I wanted to return 'Ahmed' since it matches partially with row 1, sheet 1

The Vloopup (approx match) seem not to work in this case. What are the alternatives?

In simple words, i cant find a way to match  `0553400710` in one cell with `['0553400710', '0553439406']` in another

One common trend in that `['0553400710', '0553439406']` has a common trend. all the numbers are in common `' ' , ' '` between numbers and has `[ ]` between them. The other number is an input from me

Answer (score -1):

do you want an approx match or an exact match? approx match works only if the data is sorted and it will get the closest (sorta)

Do you want the closest match?

Comment: I want to match   0553400710 in one cell with ['0553400710', '0553439406'] in another

Comment: Vlookup exact match will match that cell exactly, sorted or unsorted data. If it cannot match, it will return an error.

Approx match needs sorted data. It is a very poor technique, and I there is no situation I recommend it for.

Now, I am still unsure exactly what you want to happen in many situations, and I think you will struggle to explain it (I'm slow) so I think the best solution here is for me to lead you to the well, and let you work it out. Try this website.

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/TablesAndLookups.aspx

If you are still having trouble, message here and Ill try.